# outsourcing email - google apps alternative

Tags: email, google-workspace

I have an application that needs to send email for a couple of different @mydomain.com addresses. I'd also like to be able to read any replies sent to those addresses though a web client. I don't want to install and configure my own mail server, because I don't know anything about this, and don't think learning how to administer a mail server is a good use of my time, so instead I'd like to outsource it.

Google apps is pretty much exactly what I'm after, the cost is too high considering that the volume of email I'll be sending/receiving will be relatively low and I won't be using any of the other Google apps services.

Is there an alternative service to Google apps that my app could use to send email from my domain?

Comment: Why are the "third-party or configure my own server" the only options? Most hosting companies provide you with everything you need for sending and receiving mail. Are you working with a bare-bones dedicated box, or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google apps standard edition is **free** for up to 10 user accounts (with unlimited email aliases and distribution lists which google calls nicknames and groups), it sounds like this would meet your needs, [you can sign up here](http://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new).

Beyond that most hosting companies offer email account management and usually a free webmail client like horde on top of pop3 and IMAP services. You might want to check with your host or domain registrar and see if you already have access to this kind of service.

Comment: As of 06 Dec 2012 there is no longer a free version of Google Apps - http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2855120